# Vim folding very slow on large file

Tags: vimrc

I have a large python file (~ 4k loc) and even if I do one manual fold in the code, it seems like all actions take about 3x longer to do, regardless of whether it's in or out of the fold, close or far from the fold. Normally without any folds, the file is fine.

Are folds not suggested on large files or something (> 500loc), or is there a way to get around this? Note that the folds are **all manual**, so I don't think (or hope there shouldn't be) any calculation related to where the code-folds should be or not. (Note also that these are not necessarily my python files, so I can't tell someone to "make the files smaller so it works better in my vim setup".)

Comment: Depending on how the folding is defined, it can indeed be extremely slow. I had to cache previous computations to avoid some kind of recursive analysis (IIRC) in my [C&C++ folding plugin](https://github.com/LucHermitte/VimFold4C/). I've seen a folding plugin for Python that uses the same kind of approach. Both suffer of the same issue: folds can quickly become out-of-sync.